# Multidimensional array declaration in ocean script

Tags: linux

How to declare multidimensional array in ocean scripts.I am facing problem as ocean only allows declaring one dimensional array

Comment: Are you talking about this: https://secure.engr.oregonstate.edu/wiki/ams/index.php/Cadence/WritingCadenceOCEANScripts ?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way this is handled in C is by allocating a one-dimensional array of the appropriate total size: e.g. an array of `X` by `Y` by `Z` elements would be defined as a 1D array of size `X*Y*Z`. Then you access it with an appropriate 'index expression', something like `i*Z*Y + j*Z + k`. If that expression appears more than once in your code, then it's best to abstract it into a function or macro.

That abstraction also lets you easily change the data layout to match the access pattern, to get the best performance.